# Algorithm to find rectangle inside a triangle

Tags: geometry, algorithms, triangles

I am trying to write a program that generate procedural cities. 
However, I am stuck on a problem : I don't know how to subdivide a triangle into a rectangle and other triangles. I know how to subdivide into a quadrangle + triangles but I have to work with rectangles for now.

So I'm searching an algorithm that will, for any kind of triangle, find the biggest rectangle contained inside a triangle.

What I know :

- the position of the vertices of my triangle.
- not a lot of math. I would love to change that but I'm not brave enough !

Thanks.

Bump Edit : Can somebody gives me some pointers please ? It would help me a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From [this article](http://mathcountsnotes.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/the-largest-rectangle-inscribed-in-any.html) :

> Tthe maximum rectangle area occurs when the midpoints of two of the sides of the triangle were joined to make a side of the rectangle and its area is thus 50% or half of the area of the triangle or 1/4 of the base times height.

Comment: Thanks Josay. However I am searching an algorithm to find the positions of the vertices of the rectangle.

Comment: It's basic geometry to have the positions of the middle of two sides of the triangle and their projections on the third side.

Comment: Would you give me some directions please ? 
I wonder if projecting the middle of two sides on the third side always results in a rectangle. I must work with rectangle here. Thanks